# Not Able To Post Image From My Form Using Ajax updater() of prototype.js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I am trying to submit my form using new Ajax updater() method of prototype.js. When I check request in my controller i found the image field is not present. After reading few articles I came to know there is some complexity saving images using Ajax. here is my template code:-

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function showWaitingImage( divId ){
        $(divId).innerHTML = "<img src='../spinner.gif'/>Loading...";
    } 
    this.showWaitingImage = showWaitingImage    

    function SubmitStudentinfo() {
        new Ajax.Updater( 'main-form','{{ path('CollageStudentBundle_studentinfo_new') }}', { method: 'post', evalScripts : true, parameters: $('student-form').serialize() , onLoading : showWaitingImage('main-form') } );
    }
    this.SubmitStudentinfo = SubmitStudentinfo

 </script>

 <div id="main-form">
<form {{ form_enctype(form) }} name="student-form" id="student-form" >

{{ form_errors(form) }}

    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="100%" >
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.bloodgroup, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-medium1'} }) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.dob, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-medium1'} }) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.program_id, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-medium1'} }) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.category_id, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-medium1'} }) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.picture, { 'attr': {'class': 'input-medium'} }) }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="button" value="Save And Next" onclick="SubmitStudentinfo();"  />
</form>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can post the image along with the form. Or is there any ting else that i need to follow to store image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX cannot upload files. There are workarounds such as submitting a form from an iframe, this is how [Ajax Upload plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) works.

---

With HTML5 you can now use [`FormData`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-formdata) to upload files, but not in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I downloaded the plugin, but when i opened client/demo.htm and tried with a simple file..it popsup Failed. please help

Comment: I've not used it myself, and "Failed" isn't informative. Be sure to [follow the instructions](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload#readme) and perhaps look for others [who had similar problems](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload/issues).